# When CE Cache is disabled via the config variable, is there still processing overhead?

Tags: add-on, performance, ce-cache, hosting

I have a current site in development on EE 2.5.3. I'm using the latest CE Cache but have it disabled via the `ce_cache_off` global in my config.

I'm running into some really slow performance in general, most notably refreshing the Structure view.

That view only has 53 queries, which seems normal to me. It's taking upwards of 8 seconds to load, however, and this is at EngineHosting on their Virtual Server Cluster plan that costs $400 a month.

I can't imagine that this is normal and I'm hoping to rule out a server issue. (I currently have a ticket open with EngineHosting and even Greg Aker is going to take a look.)

Does anyone know if CE Cache still does its cache busting and refreshing when disabled via config?

Comment: Still wondering if anyone knows how CE Cache works under the covers when disabled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a non issue due to a recent posting by EngineHosting:

http://updates.enginehosting.com/post/37208191032/vsc-performance-impacts

Answer (score 3):

EngineHosting just posted something about that was effecting performance on some VSC clusters, see http://updates.enginehosting.com/post/37208191032/vsc-performance-impacts

But as you say, 53 queries isn't many. Though you may also want to look to see how much memory is used to load the page as well.